# List of output currents in test conditions in CMOS buffer's datasheets

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, buffer

in datasheets of commonly used CMOS buffers output low voltages are given at specific currents (100uA, 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA). 100uA current shows that the buffer has CMOS output driver, but i still wonder why manufacturer uses exactly this currents as test conditions? Does this refer to any standard? (I was trying to find answer in JEDEC standards, but still have no luck)

Answer (score 0):

CMOS buffers have a specific ‘on’ resistance, Rds(on). The on resistance will vary with process and temperature.

But rather than state Rds(on) as a range, they characterize the buffers to meet specified Voh/Vol for the I/O standard they’re designed to drive. I suppose that saves you the trouble of figuring that out from Rds(on).

As to why those particular values, they’re powers of 2. ASIC libraries are the same way. It makes sense when you consider how pads are configured, as transistor regions that get turned on in chunks to achieve the desired drive strength.

Comment: I think the question is why those **specific values** of current are used in the specifications. It seems that the OP understands that \$V_{OL}\$ is a function of \$I_{OL}\$.